# Spring java ResponseEntity<T> with multiple parameter types

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working with java and Spring MVC, In the first version of the app I was response with a `ResponseEntity<String>` and where I haved and error I returned something like `return new ResponseEntity<String>(httpErrors.toString(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);` and when all were right something like `return new ResponseEntity<String>(loginResponse.toString(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);`. But now I believe theres is a better way to do it, without using the `toString()` method, returning the specific object according to the case like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class LoginController {

    /** The login service to validate the user. */
    @Autowired
    LoginService loginService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> validate(@RequestBody final UserLog login) {

        WebUser webUser = loginService.getUserDetails(login.getLogin(), login.getPassword());
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        if (webUser == null) {
            HttpErrors httpErrors = new HttpErrors(ApiCommonResources.ERROR_402, "error" + "." + ApiCommonResources.ERROR_402, ApiCommonResources.ERROR_402_TEXT);
            return new ResponseEntity<HttpErrors>(httpErrors, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        List<Account> userAccounts = loginService.getMerchantAccounts(webUser.getMerchantId());

        // Json Web Token builder
        token = "b7d22951486d713f92221bb987347777";

        LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse(ApiCommonResources.SUCCESS_REQUEST_CODE, token);

        return new ResponseEntity<LoginResponse>(loginResponse, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

}
```

The question is how can I create a class that can wraps the `LoginResponse` as well as `HttpErrors`object types and send it in `?` as the returning object in ResponseEntity:

LoginResponse class:

```
public class LoginResponse{

    public LoginResponse(Integer statusCode, String token){
        this.setStatusCode(statusCode);
        this.setToken(token);
    }

    private String token;
    private Integer statusCode;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public Integer getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        StringBuilder jsonResponse = new StringBuilder();

        jsonResponse.append("{");
        jsonResponse.append("\"statusCode\":");
        jsonResponse.append("\"" + statusCode + "\",");
        jsonResponse.append("\"token\":");
        jsonResponse.append("\"" + token + "\"");
        jsonResponse.append("}");

        return jsonResponse.toString();
    }

}
```

And HttpErrors class:

```
public class HttpErrors {

    public HttpErrors(){
    }

    public HttpErrors(String errorCode, String errorKey, String errorMessage) {
        super();
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorKey = errorKey;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    private String errorCode;
    private String errorKey;
    private String errorMessage;

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorKey() {
        return errorKey;
    }

    public void setErrorKey(String errorKey) {
        this.errorKey = errorKey;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        StringBuilder jsonError = new StringBuilder();

        jsonError.append("{");
        jsonError.append("\"errorCode\":");
        jsonError.append("\"" + errorCode + "\",");
        jsonError.append("\"errorKey\":");
        jsonError.append("\"" + errorKey + "\",");
        jsonError.append("\"errorMessage\":");
        jsonError.append("\"" + errorMessage + "\"");
        jsonError.append("}");

        return jsonError.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: use generics, make LoginResponse extend an abstract generic response type...also put all common methods llike status codes an stuff in it.

Comment: Thanks @yUdoDis, can you help me with an example, please?

Comment: Consider using ControllerAdvice for controllers exception handling and responding with proper messages and HttpStatus, some random example that i googled now: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/controlleradvice-improvements-in-spring.html

Comment: @AndreFontaine sorry bout the delay i've posted

Comment: Dont forget to mark as answered :)!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Response<T> {

   private int httpStatus;
   private T data;

   //getter and setter consructor

    eg constructors
    public RestResponse(T data){
    this(HTTP_OK,data)
    }

    public RestResponse(int httpStatus,T data){
    this.httpStatus = httpStaus;
    this.data = data;  

  }
```

Now just use this template for all your response objects (repsone objects can be POJOs too)

```
return new RestEntity<LoginResponse>(loginResponse,statusCode) //loginResponse object
```

where LoginResponse is

```
public class LoginResponse {
private String token;
//getter and setter and constructors.
}
```

You should take some  time to establish a REST contracts (Read about it using google :)) and then just follow through using this basic logic. Java and spring are magic together.
Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like this (in my opinion it will be more elegant)

create a method in controller which returns `LoginResponse`, but firstly perform validation of the input `UserLog` and once there are any issues, throw a custom exception, which in the end will be caught by the `exceptionHandler`

take a look at my example controller

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {
    private ProductRequestValidator productRequestValidator;

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
        binder.addValidators(productRequestValidator);
    }

    @Autowired
    public ProductController(ProductRequestValidator productRequestValidator, ProductService productService) {
        this.productRequestValidator = productRequestValidator;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<ProductResponse> retrieveProducts(@Valid @RequestBody ProductRequest requestProduct, BindingResult bindingResult)
            throws ValidationException {

        // validate input and throw exception if any error occured
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            throw new ValidationException(bindingResult);
        }

        // business logic
        return new ProductRequest();
}
```

if you want you can check my bitbucket project which has it all implemented:

- [controller](https://bitbucket.org/akfaz/thepriceisright/src/5aaa10906a442fecf52a342f88911b03c3cd5e54/tpir-mvc/src/main/java/org/bitbucket/akfaz/tpir/mvc/controller/ProductController.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)
- [exceptionHandler](https://bitbucket.org/akfaz/thepriceisright/src/5aaa10906a442fecf52a342f88911b03c3cd5e54/tpir-mvc/src/main/java/org/bitbucket/akfaz/tpir/mvc/controller/ExceptionHandlerController.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)
- [customException](https://bitbucket.org/akfaz/thepriceisright/src/5aaa10906a442fecf52a342f88911b03c3cd5e54/tpir-mvc/src/main/java/org/bitbucket/akfaz/tpir/mvc/exception/ValidationException.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)
- [customValidator](https://bitbucket.org/akfaz/thepriceisright/src/5aaa10906a442fecf52a342f88911b03c3cd5e54/tpir-mvc/src/main/java/org/bitbucket/akfaz/tpir/mvc/validator/ProductRequestValidator.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)